# Prevent daemons from starting automatically during Centos6 update

Tags: linux, centos, rpm, yum, rhel

There is a simple way to do it on Debian using the policy-rc.d trick https://wiki.debian.org/chroot#Configuration
Is there such thing in Centos6?

Comment: What's the question here exactly? That linked section doesn't seem to have anything to do with updates (or much of anything else) and mostly seems to be a horrible trick to prevent dpkg (at least) from starting daemons in a chroot by short-circuiting the scripts that it normally runs.

Answer (score 0):

RPM has the ability to disable %pre/%post/%preun/%postun
scripts when installing using --nopre/--nopost/--nopreun/--nopostun
options resp.

Most daemons are restarted in %post, so --post would prevent
daemon restart.

However, most daemons are restarted if (and only if) already enabled
to be started on reboot by chkconfig(1) (or systemctl). So in practice
nothing whatsoever needs to be done if the chroot is being populated
by a single transaction because most daemons are not yet configured
to be run.